# Error Loading acl file in mosquitto

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

This is my acl file.

```
 topic sampletopic
```

And in Mosquitto.conf file path to acl is set as below

```
 acl_file ‪aclfile.conf
```

Following is the error log

```
 1454515084: mosquitto version 1.4.7 (build date 28/12/2015 21:28:48.57) starting
 1454515084: Config loaded from C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
 1454515084: Error: Unable to open acl_file "‪aclfile.conf".
 1454515084: Error opening acl file "‪aclfile.conf".
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is your acl file on disk?

Comment: yes, it's on the disk. Actuall entry on the mosquitto.comf file is acl_file ‪C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\aclfile.conf.

Does this have any impact on windows 8.1, Anything related file permission. ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when starting mosquitto windows service and found out what is the problem.

Although acl file is in the same directory with mosquitto, you still need to specify full path of the acl file location.

The following demonstrates the correct and wrong way of writing your `mosquitto.conf` file

**Wrong**

```
acl_file aclfile.conf
```

**Wrong**

```
acl_file "C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\aclfile.conf"
```

**Correct** (please take note, the is no quotes "")

```
acl_file C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\aclfile.conf
```

**Correct** (works with environmental variable)

```
acl_file %ProgramFiles(x86)%\mosquitto\aclfile.conf
```